# Why softmax is working fine but not sigmoid in mnist fasion keras code?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have simple Keras code for multi-label classification,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import keras

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2],1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Summary,
[image]

Now, as you can see in the last layer I have used 'sigmoid', but as it is multi-label classification, I want to use sigmoid. But I am getting the follwing error if I do the same.

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape
>   (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

What could be the fix here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `loss='binary_crossentropy'` to `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`.

Use `categorical_crossentropy` when the labels are [one-hot encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). Otherwise, use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

`binary_crossentropy` is used in case of two classes and it outputs a single neuron (or in case of multi-output classification it can outputput more than one neuron). For example, if the value of neuron is greater than `0.5` than you pick class `1`, otherwise you pick class `0` (or you don't pick any class if the value is lower than some threshold).

Also, in some `keras`/`tf.keras` versions the fashion MNIST is given without the channels dimension so you should add it manually:

```py
x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1), np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
```

Comment: updated again, should be `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: worked with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, and other changes were not necessary. Could you please elaborate.